# Clearing All Hidden Cells in a Range

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

Very simple question. I keep getting error messages and excel crashing. What is wrong with my code:

```
Sub Clear()

Dim c As Range

For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("HeatPump1").Cells

    If c.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
        c.Clear
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Change `.Cells` to `.Rows`

Comment: The code works fine for me.  (I assumed that "HeatPump1" is a range on the ActiveSheet.)

Answer (score 1):

Which line is throwing an error?  Do you have a range named "HeatPump1" in the active sheet when the code is running?

On a side note, c.EntireRow.Hidden is a boolean value, so you don't need to check if it is true.  You can simply write:

```
    If c.EntireRow.Hidden Then
```

Comment: Kudos for `If {bool-expression} Then`, where comparing `{bool-expression}` to a `Boolean` value is redundant.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - That issue, and the related `If x = True Then` `y = True` `Else` `y = False` `End If` (which simplifies to `y = x`), always annoy me!